# Send Docker Context as Tar with Go Client can't find Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, docker-api

I am using the [Go Docker Client](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client) to attempt to build an image from a `Dockerfile` whose contents are defined in code.

According to the [Docker Daemon API Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#build-image-from-a-dockerfile)

> The input stream must be a tar archive...
>
> ...The archive must include a build instructions file, typically called Dockerfile at the archive’s root.

So I want to create the build context in code, write it to a tar file, then send that to the Docker Daemon to be built.  To do this I can use the [ImageBuild function](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ImageBuild) and pass in the tar file (build context) as an `io.ReadCloser`.  As long as my `Dockerfile` is at the root of that compressed archive, it should find it and build it.

However, I get the common error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Which obviously means that it can't find the Dockerfile at the root of the archive.  I am unsure why.  I believe the way I am doing this adds a `Dockerfile` to the root of the tar archive.  The daemon should see this.  What am I misunderstanding here?

code snippet to reproduce

```
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(&buf)

    contents := "FROM alpine\nCMD [\"echo\", \"this is from the archive\"]"

    if err := tarWriter.WriteHeader(&tar.Header{
        Name:     "Dockerfile",
        Mode:     777,
        Size:     int64(len(contents)),
        Typeflag: tar.TypeReg,
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if _, err := tarWriter.Write([]byte(contents)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := tarWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    reader := tar.NewReader(&buf)
    c, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = c.ImageBuild(context.Background(), reader, types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Context:    reader,
        Dockerfile: "Dockerfile",
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

go.mod file

```
module docker-tar

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/docker/distribution v2.7.1+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/docker v1.13.1
    github.com/docker/go-connections v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-units v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/go-digest v1.0.0-rc1 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20191112182307-2180aed22343 // indirect
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a zero in front of `777` for octal numeral system: `0777`, `0o777`, or `0O777`
2. Use `reader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())` not `tar.NewReader(&buf)`
3. Use `client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation()` for newer versions too.
4. Try this working version:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(&buf)
    contents := `FROM alpine:3.10.3
CMD ["echo", "this is from the archive"]
`
    header := &tar.Header{
        Name:     "Dockerfile",
        Mode:     0o777,
        Size:     int64(len(contents)),
        Typeflag: tar.TypeReg,
    }
    err := tarWriter.WriteHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = tarWriter.Write([]byte(contents))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tarWriter.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    c, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(c.ClientVersion())

    reader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()) // tar.NewReader(&buf)
    ctx := context.Background()
    buildOptions := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Context:    reader,
        Dockerfile: "Dockerfile",
        Tags:       []string{"alpine-echo:1.2.4"},
    }
    _, err = c.ImageBuild(ctx, reader, buildOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Output for `docker image ls` after `go run .`:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine-echo                      1.2.4               d81774f32812        26 seconds ago      5.55MB
alpine                           3.10.3              b168ac0e770e        4 days ago          5.55MB
```

Output for `docker run alpine-echo:1.2.4`:

```
this is from the archive
```

Note: You may need to edit `FROM alpine:3.10.3` for your specific version.

Comment: I don't understand how `0777` is allowed for octal instead the more explicit `0o777`. It's misleading and it's really not clear to me what it adds as value .

Comment: See: ` mode = os.ModeDir | 0777`  line 317 file `go1.13.4.src/src/archive/zip/struct.go` and 129 search results for `0777`

Comment: I'm not arguing at all about whether or nor it is allowed, I'm more interested about why it is. If anyone else cares, this has been discussed a lot apparently: [Proposal: Go 2 Number Literal Changes](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/19308-number-literals.md), [#151](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12711) and [#12711](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/151).

Comment: [Integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals):  An integer literal is a sequence of digits representing an integer constant. An optional prefix sets a non-decimal base: 0b or 0B for binary, **0, 0o, or 0O for octal**, and 0x or 0X for hexadecimal. A single 0 is considered a decimal zero. In hexadecimal literals, letters a through f and A through F represent values 10 through 15.